# Howto get the filepath of a rendered animation frame with python

Tags: rendering, scripting, python, image

I want to modify every frame in an animation after it has been saved as an image. Since `bpy.data.images["Render Result"]` doesn't have associated data I need to load it from disk.

How do I get the path of the last rendered frame in a `render_post` handler?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The filepath is stored in:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath
```

However there is a function to find the output filename for a frame (the same function blender uses internally).

```
output = bpy.context.scene.render.frame_path(frame=10)
```

example use:

```
>>> bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "/test/some_###_anim.png"
>>> bpy.context.scene.render.frame_path(frame=10)
'/test/some_010_anim.png'
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to use `context.scene.render.filepath` and append the frame number with (using `str.zfill(4)` where str is the frame number as a string and 4 is the number of digits), and extension using context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format, converted to lower case (using `str.lower()`).

Comment: What about '#' in the output filepath?

Comment: '#' indicates padding, so you could count the number of '#'s after the last slash (in case folder names have hashes) and use that instead of 4

Comment: You'd also have to remove the hashes from the output path using `str.replace('#', '')`

Comment: Could you update your answer with a complete code example for all this please?

Comment: Now that would make it too easy wouldn't it ;) Figuring it out by yourself will teach you something. If you're still stuck tomorrow then I'll code it for you.

Comment: use of `str.zfill(4)` and `file_format.lower()` are incorrect, the `#` characters can be in the middle of a string and fileformat enum doesnt always match the extension. Getting this right is quite involved, an API function is provided to do this. (noted in my own answer)

Answer (score -2):

The expression you want is `bpy.context.scene.render.frame_path()`

Calling `frame_path` without specifying a frame uses the current frame.

```
import bpy

def handle_render_write(scn):
    print(scn.render.frame_path())

bpy.app.handlers.render_write.append(handle_render_write)
```